python web crawling using selenium fail in pressing the export button due to screen size
I try to press a export button in a web page, but it fail. But once I artificially zoom out (CONTROL, -) in the webpage, the selenium can click the button with driver.find_element(By.ID,"BUTTON_EXPORT").click()
So I try to mimic the zoom out practice using ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(Keys.SUBTRACT).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform(), but no luck.
Tried driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'"). The webpage can actually zoom out, while the selenium still cannot click the button (even the button is shown in screen).
Tried adjust the screen size in chromedriver options, options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080") or options.add_argument("--window-size=2560,1440") or set the window size with driver.set_window_size(2560, 1440). Still no luck.
The actual webpage display in screen"

The source code of it:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var _Scale = (screen.height / 1800) * 0.95;
        
        document.getElementById("viewport").content = "width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale="+_Scale+", maximum-scale="+_Scale+", user-scalable=no";
        
        window.onload = function(){
            window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                return "";
            }
            
            window.onunload = function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:   "GET",
                    async:  false,
                    url:    "logout.php?silence=1"
                });
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <frameset frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame src="frame.php?url=index2.php" name="mainFrame" title="mainFrame" />
    </frameset>
    <noframes>
        <body></body>
    </noframes>
</html>

Error Message:
---> 36 driver.find_element(By.ID,"BUTTON_EXPORT").click()
     37 driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"是").click()
     39 driver.implicitly_wait(20)

.py:94, in WebElement.click(self)
     92 def click(self) -> None:
     93     """Clicks the element."""
---> 94     self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

File py:395, in WebElement._execute(self, command, params)
    393     params = {}
    394 params["id"] = self._id
--> 395 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

py:347, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    345 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    346 if response:
...
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6489D93EB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6489C9C24]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF91529257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF915AAAA58+40]
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

iframe source code for the export button. Which cannot be displayed until I zoom out to 80% manually.
<div class="control">
                    <button class="control" type="button" id="BUTTON_REPORT" onclick="FinalCheck(false);">
                        <span class="icon-search"></span>顯示                 </button>
                    <button class="control" type="button" id="BUTTON_EXPORT" onclick="FinalCheck(true);">
                        <span class="icon-export"></span>匯出                 </button>
                    <button class="control" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='?';">
                        <span class="icon-refresh"></span>重設                    </button>
                </div>

Any clues to click the button with selenium?

You never posted the error message you are getting when it fails. Edit your question and post the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Selenium does not do well when zoomed. I would not try to zoom in/out to click the button. From the HTML you provided, there is no button. I'm assuming the button HTML is actually in the FRAME element. You will need to switch into the frame to be able to access the button. Do some reading on switching to IFRAMEs and try that.

Thanks for it. Add the error message when clicking the 'export" button. And indeed I switch to iframe that contain the button, and it was the last step of the crawling. Added the iframe source code. As my approach was trying to mimic the zoom out action which proved to be success when doing manually. While in selenium, no matter what I try to zoom out, still no luck....
